# Output File is missing padding at the end of the file for a Bitmap. Why is this?

Tags: c++, c, binaryfiles

In this program I am trying to use C-style files for both reading and writing these files. I am also dynamically allocating the memory onto the heap using new() and delete in order to then write that block of memory to another file. For some reason when I preform a hex hump the files are almost the same. Only the ending bytes are different.  Here are my dumps.

[image: INPUT FILE (mino.bmp)]

This is for my input file. The output should have the same data.

[image: OUTPUT FILE (test.bmp)]

This is my output file. From the dump you can see that its different at the end of the file.
Why does this happen if I use fseek() to skip the padding?

```
#include <cstdint>
#include <cstdio>

#pragma pack(push, 2)
struct BitmapFileHeader {

    uint16_t type;
    uint32_t size;
    uint16_t reserved_1;
    uint16_t reserved_2;
    uint32_t offset;

};
struct BitmapInfoHeader {

    uint32_t size;
    uint32_t width;
    uint32_t height;
    uint16_t planes;
    uint16_t bitcount;
    uint32_t compression;
    uint32_t imagesize;
    uint32_t x_pixels_per_meter;
    uint32_t y_pixels_per_meter;
    uint32_t color_used;
    uint32_t color_important;
};
#pragma pack(pop)

struct Pixel {
    uint8_t blue;
    uint8_t green;
    uint8_t red;
};

int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
    if(argc != 3) {
        printf("Usage : %s input_file output_file\n", argv[0]);
        return 1;
    }

    FILE *fin;
    FILE *fout;
    BitmapFileHeader bfh;
    BitmapInfoHeader bih;

    fin = fopen(argv[1], "rb");

    if (nullptr == fin) {
        perror(argv[1]);
        return -1;
    }

    if (sizeof(BitmapFileHeader) != fread(
        &bfh,
        1,
        sizeof(bfh),
        fin
    )) {
        printf("Unable to read bitmap file header. \n");
        return -2;
    }

    if (sizeof(BitmapInfoHeader) != fread(
        &bih,
        1,
        sizeof(bih),
        fin
    )) {
        printf("Unable to read bitmap info header. \n");
        return -3;
    }

    printf("Size of File Header = %lu\n", sizeof(BitmapFileHeader));

    int8_t first = (bfh.type >> 8) & 0xff;
    int8_t second = bfh.type & 0xff;

    if ( (first != 'M') && (second != 'B') ){
        printf("Input file is not a Bitmap file. \n");
        return -4;
    }

    printf("File type = %c%c\n", first, second);
    printf("File size = %u\n", bfh.size);
    printf("File offset = %u\n", bfh.offset);
    printf("File width = %u\n", bih.width);
    printf("Info size = %u\n", bih.size);

    uint32_t padding_bytes = 0;
    uint32_t row_bytes_final = bih.width * sizeof(Pixel);
    uint32_t row_bytes_initial = row_bytes_final;

    do{
        uint32_t rem = row_bytes_final % 4;

        if (rem != 0) {
            row_bytes_final += 1;
        }

        padding_bytes = row_bytes_final - row_bytes_initial;

    } while( (row_bytes_final % 4) != 0);


    fseek(fin, bfh.offset, SEEK_SET);

    Pixel *p = new Pixel[bih.height * bih.width];

    for (uint32_t i = 0; i < bih.height; i++) {

        for (uint32_t j = 0; j < bih.width; j++) {

            uint32_t index = i * bih.width + j;

            fread(&p[index], 1, sizeof(p[0]), fin);
        }

        fseek(fin, padding_bytes, SEEK_CUR);

    }

    fclose(fin);


    fout = fopen(argv[2], "wb");

    if(nullptr == fout) {
        perror(argv[2]);
        return -5;
    }

    if( sizeof(BitmapFileHeader) != fwrite(
    &bfh, 
    1, 
    sizeof(bfh), 
    fout
    )) {
        printf("Unable to write bitmap file header.\n");
        return -6;
    }

    if( sizeof(BitmapInfoHeader) != fwrite(
        &bih, 
        1, 
        sizeof(bih), 
        fout
        )) {
            printf("Unable to write bitmap info header.\n");
            return -7;
        }

    fseek(fout, bfh.offset, SEEK_SET);

    for (uint32_t i = 0; i < bih.height; i++) {

        for (uint32_t j = 0; j  < bih.width; j++) {

            uint32_t index = i * bih.width + j;

            fwrite(&p[index], 1, sizeof(p[0]), fout);

        }

        fseek(fout, padding_bytes, SEEK_CUR);

    }


    fclose(fout);
    delete p;


    //fseek(fin, bfh.offset, SEEK_SET);
    //Pixel p;
    //fread(&p, 1, sizeof(p), fin);
    //printf("R = %u, G = %u, B = %u\n", p.red, p.green, p.blue);
    return 0;

}
```

Comment: You need to check calls for errors. For example, you don't check if this call succeeds: `fseek(fin, padding_bytes, SEEK_CUR);`. Likely, it fails, explaining your problem.

Comment: @David Schwartz I will try that! Thanks.

Comment: @DavidSchwartz I checked this and every call returned zero. Upon reading the documentation this means the call successfully performed the operation. I also did this for the other calls for binary files.

Comment: the posted code contains both C and C++ statements.  Please make a choice for which language you are using, then correct the list of 'tags'

Comment: @user3629249 Understood. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Seeking to a position off the end of the file does not automatically pad it.  Padding bytes will only be written on a subsequent write.

You can force this last padding to be written after your loop finishes as follows:

```
if (padding_bytes > 0) {
    fseek(fout, -1, SEEK_CUR);
    fputc('\0', fout);
}
```

By the way, you are using the wrong `delete` for your array.  Instead use array-delete (corresponding to the array-alloc):

```
delete[] p;
```